# Why do we store password hashes in the same database as the application data? (Or: Is there any reason we don't store them in a different database?)

Tags: passwords

With all the hacks and leaks and whatnot lately, I've been thinking about this a lot. It's (near) impossible to lock down your entire application to make sure there are no SQL injection points, or any other attacks that could result in database disclosure.

However, it would be quite easy to audit an application for SQL injection if it was very, *very* small and very, *very* simple. One could store passwords in a totally separate database, with no access to it at all except through an API. This API would have say, three methods: check_password, add_password, change_password.

This way, when (and it is when, not if, if you are a large enough target) someone figures out a way to dump your database through some security flaw in your web application, they still don't have your password hashes.

Having thought of this idea it seems blindingly obvious, but I haven't found any references to it anywhere else, so my question is: **Why shouldn't we do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Where do you store the password for the password database?

Comment: What do you mean by password? The password to the database would be stored in the configuration on the API server. The API itself probably wouldn't have a password (could just federate access with firewalls).